# What is this tropical plant with woody vines and waxy leaves?

Tags: identification, tropical

What is this tropical houseplant? I've had it for 15 years in a small pot and it grows woody vines with with waxy leaves and never gets rootbound.

[image]

Comment: It looks remarkably like  a Hoya,but you haven't mentioned flowers - has it never had any?

Comment: Remarkable age for a cutie like this 

Answer (score 6):

This is [Hoya carnosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoya_carnosa) and it requires bright light for flowering. It's easy to propagate; I have 11 plants like this from 11 leaves of the original plant.

Answer (score -1):

This looks like Evergreen Clematis.  A wonderful evergreen vine suitable for zone 5 and up.  15 years?  Clematis armandii.  White flowers with an almost too strong scent!  I could be very wrong about the ID.  15 YEARS??  Never gets rootbound?  You are saying you've never transplanted this plant in 15 YEARS??

Let's see if others can more accurately ID first.  Has this plant never flowered?  Indoors with little sun this makes sense.  Have you ever fertilized?  Hoya could be a candidate by Bamboo.

Comment: Sorry, stormy but to anyone who's ever had a hoya as a houseplant, it's instantly recognizable. Alina's answer is correct.

Comment: Grins, Jude!  I haven't had a hoya as a houseplant!  Can I be forgiven?  Evergreen clematis is decidedly different with the impressed veins.  I just was dumbfounded this plant is 15 years old.

Comment: I'll forgive you as your forté is landscaping. Hoya' can last for many decades if cared for properly. Mine died (along with many other houseplants) when I had pneumonia and was bedridden for 2 entire months. I wasn't concerned about any plants. I don't like to see good plants die but they can always be replaced. I'm not a sentimental person who attaches significance to objects.

Comment: Plants aren't objects in my world.  They are family.  Grinning widely!  Pneumonia is horrible!!  I've had it twice...had a horse accident that collapsed my lung and there was no anesthesiologist around so they took this bic pen thing and pushed it through to my lung to blow it up.  Propensity now for pleura pneumonia.  Incredibly horrible.  My first was on a vacation to see my kids.  I've also gone through pertussis with my 3 month old son.  That took 2 months.  You have the right attitude and when you are sick sick sick you wouldn't be able to think any other way.